# using val('') to clear a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm placing some default content into a `<textarea>` using jquery, but then trying to implement a button to clear any new user made additions to the `<textarea>` by resetting to the original. I've tried using `.val('')` triggered by an jquery click function to clear the `<textarea>` before restarting the code again, but for some reason the `<textarea>` remains blank after I try to reset (works find first time through). Can't figure this one out!

The code is something I'm working on to teach correct comma usage in an English class. Working on it here: https://codepen.io/brentsimpson/pen/EvveKw

```
function start() {

var text = "We need walnuts, cinnamon, sugar, and milk.";  
var newText;
var selectComma = ","; // this could be any punctuation you want
var hits = [];
var commaCheck;
var commaPlacement;
var progressBar = 0;
var offset = 0;

newText = text.replace(/,/g, '');

$("#commabox").text(newText); //writes newText to textarea
$("#commanumber").text(commanumbertext);

console.log("The sentence is " + text.length + " characters long.");

for(i = 0; i<text.length; i++){
if(text[i] === selectComma){
  commaPlace = i - offset;
  offset = offset + 1;
  hits.push(commaPlace);
    }
}

var commaNumber = hits.length;
var commanumbertext = "There should be " + commaNumber + " commas in this sentence.";
var progressBarProgress = Math.round(100 / hits.length);
$("#progressbardisplay").css('width', progressBar + "%"); // resets the progress bar

console.log("Commas were placed at these characters: " + hits);


/* code runs after keypress and checks if a comma has been placed
   at a place where one was removed */
$( "#commabox" ).keypress(function( event ) {
    commaCheck = event.which;
    console.log( commaCheck + " was pressed." );
    var caret = $("#commabox").caret();
    commaPlacement = caret["begin"]; //assigns value of begin in caret object to commaPlacement
    console.log("Comma placed at " + commaPlacement);
    checkCommaPlacement();
            });

/* this function checks if commas have been placed at the 
 right place in the string. Could probably use indexOf() here instead 
*/
function checkCommaPlacement() {
    a = hits.indexOf(commaPlacement);
    if (commaCheck === 44 && a != -1) {
        progressBar = progressBar + progressBarProgress;
    $("#progressbardisplay").css('width', progressBar + "%");
    console.log("Comma is in array at " + a);
    for (var i = a; i < commaNumber; i++){
        hits[i] += 1; // updates the array places above comma
      }} else {
    console.log("Comma incorrecly placed.") }               
   };

};

start();

$( ".btn" ).click(function() {
  $('#commabox').val('');
  start();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.val(newText)` instead of `.text(newText)` to set the text of the textarea:

```
$("#commabox").val(newText); //writes newText to textarea
```

Answer (score 0):

This here should be enough for what you're trying to achieve:

```js
$('document').ready(function() { 
  
  var $textarea = $('#textarea1');
  
  $textarea.attr('data-default-value', $textarea.val());
  
  $('#clear').click(function() {
    $textarea.val($textarea.data('default-value'));
  });
  
});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea1">Default value</textarea>

<button id="clear">Clear</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```